# Espresso doesn't run Activity test with Gif animation

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-espresso

I am trying to test intents  in `Activity` and some button clicks in `Fragment` (which is in the same activity) with `Espresso` but the problem is the `Fragment` contains a custom view with `Gif` animation in it. The custom view is basically a variation of `Movie` class to display `Gif`. **The error** I get is

> Could not launch intent Intent within 45 seconds. Perhaps the main
>   thread has not gone idle within a reasonable amount of time

So it indicates I suppose that Gif causes the main thread to be loaded and the test cannot run. 
What I **tried:**

1. Turn off all tree animation scales in Dev options (tried 2 devices)
2. Using Ui automator and running shell adb command to turn animation off
3. Trying to set the view with Gif's visibility to gone during the test

**Non of which didn't work**. I suppose that this custom view is not considered animation by the platform and doesn't get turned off. I can still see it. And I tried to `findViewById` and setting visibility to `gone`. The view is still there when the test is started. I think making view gone is a good workaround so maybe someone knows the way!

My test code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) public class TutorialActivityTest {

    private TutorialActivity tutorialActivity;
    private TutorialFragment tutorialFragment;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<TutorialActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TutorialActivity.class);

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        tutorialActivity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
        //tried to set visibility there with fragment.getView().findViewById... And also in the test directly

    @Test
    public void testOpenMainPageIntentFired() {
        Intents.init();
        tutorialActivity.openMainPage();
        intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));
        Intents.release();
    }
```

Comment: have you figured this out, I have the same problem

Comment: No, I haven't, It wasn't required to ui test this class after all. But movie is not animation so I still think that the best thing is to make view that contains gif "gone", but I didn't go this path as far as to make it work! if you figure out how to do it, make sure to post an answer to this question!

Answer (score 1):

Since the GIF animation will prevent going into an IDLE state, I'll suggest passing a static mock image resource where the GIF is supposed to go during tests. In this way, you don't have to hide the view and still test the layout composition as it will be on production.